# Oracle: Do queries starting with comments have impact on performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-execution-plan

I am adding comments to the beginning of my queries (in Oracle) to provide metadata information about the query itself.

Every information that I found out regarding this topic is only about hints besides this one: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:93449400346099694.

Will this query be interpreted the same way by the execution plan with and without the comments? Will my comment have any impact regarding performance or caching?

Comment: . . Comments should make no different on the execution plan unless they contain hints.  And why doesn't the referenced column answer your question?

Comment: And I think that applies to any database. Not only Oracle.

Comment: If you paste in a megabyte worth of comments, I'd be surprised if you didn't see a performance impact while the parser was struggling to skip over all that. Simultaneously, there'd be no impact while the query was running because the comments aren't part of the execution plan. The only interesting bit is whether or not comments affect query plan caching. For SQL Server, for example, the answer is yes -- queries must be textually identical to map to the same cached plans (ignoring forced plans). And SQL Server doesn't use hints in comments, so that's not an impediment.

Comment: Comments don't change anything, it's different with optimizer hints that look similar `/*+ ... */` (note the additional `+`). They may change the plan that the optimizer uses to perform the query task...

Answer (score 3):

When you run a query the first time then Oracle creates the execution plan and caches this plan for further use.

When you add an arbitrary comment then in fact you run a different query and thus Oracle evaluates a new execution plan. In general this execution plan could be different to the first one - although rather unlikely.

I remember in a training the trainer showed us the "secret" Oracle hint `/*+ RUN_FASTER */` - in deed the query was executing much faster! The trick was, for the original query he stored a prepared execution plan (see [Using Plan Stability](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/outlines.htm#g35579)) forcing a *Full Table Scan*. With the "hint" `/*+ RUN_FASTER */` you have a new query and the optimizer evaluated a new better plan.

In fact hints like `/*+ RUN_SLOWER */` or `/*+ drink a cup of tea */` do the same but without astonishment from the students. :-)

Answer (score 1):

adding comments to queries is a sensible strategy in my opinion - in Oracle as in other RDBMS. But in Oracle there are indeed some situations in which a comment may have an impact on the execution plan: for example there are some plan management strategies (sql baselines for example) that match a query to a plan (or rather a set of hints), and the matching is based on the sql_id - and this sql_id changes, if a different comment is added.

Another problem is, that mixing optimizer hints (`/*+ ... */`) with leading comments may lead to an invalidation of the hints - as shown in https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/adding-comments-to-sql-statements-improves-performance/.

So I would always encourage the use of comments, but separate them from hints and try to find out, if a given query is subject of plan management (taking a look at `v$sql` and its columns `SQL_PLAN_BASELINE` - and maybe also `SQL_PATCH`, which is another option to combine queries with additional execution information).